# Uploading image files to a folder + link in database without using form input issue

Tags: php, file, input

have been struggling with an issue for a while now, and hope someone can help me here.

I am creating a PHP project to enter items into a database plus corresponding images.
The page that I created to enter a single item plus its image is working smoothly.
Now, I would like to create another page in my project (that uses already working functions from the input single items page) where a user can upload items+images automatically by using a CSV file that is selected via input type=file, together with all corresponding images. Those images are not in the excel file, but stored in a folder called c:\Uploads and should be moved to a another folder + link added in the database. The items have a certain name (for example apple)in column A of the csv file, and the corresponding image in the Uploads folder is named apple.jpg for example.

The csv file upload itself is working fine, but have a lot of issues with the images. They are not selected from the form, but by using :

```
$dirContent = glob("uploads/ExcelUpload/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

This does give me an array of the files, but the problem is, I require the file itself and not the file path as a string.

```
$handle = fopen($fileTmpName, "r");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
              $dt = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
              $now = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
              $data = json_encode($data,true);
              $data = explode(";", $data);
              $data[0] = ltrim($data[0],'"[');
              $uniqueQuery = Items::findItemnumber($data[0]);
              $itemnr = isset($uniqueQuery->itemnumber);
              if ($itemnr != $data[0]){
                $mainQuery = "INSERT into items (`user_id`,`item`,`name`,`alias`,`body`,`created_at`,`updated_at`)
                                              values('".$user."','".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$now."','".$now.")";
                $result1 = $db->query($mainQuery);
                foreach($dirContent as $f){
                  $e = 0;
                  $imageinfo = getimagesize($f);
                  $size = filesize($f);
                  $image = $f;
                  $f = json_encode($f,true);
                  $f = explode("/",$f);
                  $f[2] = rtrim($f[2],'"');
                  $f2 = explode(".",$f[2]);
                  if ($f2[0] == $data[0]){
                      $_FILES['itemImages']['name'] = explode('  ',$f[2]);
                      $_FILES['itemImages']['type'] = explode('  ',$imageinfo['mime']);
                      $_FILES['itemImages']['tmp_name'] = explode('  ',$image);
                      $_FILES['itemImages']['error'] = array_map('intval', explode('  ',$e));
                      $_FILES['itemImages']['size'] = array_map('intval', explode('  ',$size));
                      $uploads = new Uploads($_FILES['itemImages']);
                      itemImages::uploadItemImages($itemid->{'id'},$uploads);
```

The value of :

```
$_FILES['itemImages']['tmp_name']
```

I get is just the string, for example "c:\Uploads\apple.jpg". I however need it to be the actual image (the tmp name it has when uploaded like a form input on the server). Have been trying many things already, but do not seem to find anything useful. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: You are overwriting `$_FILES['itemImages']['tmp_name'] = explode('  ',$image);` ... and *"the tmp name it has when uploaded like a form input on the server)"* is only for uploaded files through a form with `POST` (using `is_uploaded_file()` and the like). Its unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish here given these issues.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response ! Well, basically, my "new Uploads" class is expecting a file, while I only send the file path to it. The $image variable contains the file path (c:\Uploads\apple.jpg for example). I need to send the "real" file to my Uploads class, and not its file path. What I am trying to achieve is to turn my file path into a "real" file on the server so I can process it from there. Any help will be much appreciated, has been kept me busy for quite a while now. Am still quite newbe in the developer world .. :)

Comment: So basically, my question is, can you turn a file path string into $_FILES ?

Comment: If the file is still on someone's computer (C: drive)... and you are just sending the csv to the server (which has a list of file paths)... no. A server nor browser cannot dig into a persons drive to grab the files in that way. You must also send each image file to the server through a POST (or ajax POST) with user selection (they must select each file, its a security thing you see). But then to know which file uploaded is what is in the csv, you will have to look at the filename provided in the $_POST var before you overwrite it. Its complicated ;)